# Can you evaluate the Berry phase integral?

Tags: condensed-matter, berry-pancharatnam-phase

[image: Image taken from the book Topological insulators and Topological superconductors By B. Andrei Berneveg]
This is my first post. Can anyone simplify the integral in eq(8.16) in the picture. How the integral is evaluated ? How the sign function came to the scenarion? The pic taken from the book "Topological insulators and Topological superconductors" By B. Andrei Berneveg.
[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2):

$$
I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+m^2)^{3/2}}dx=2/|m|
$$
and $m/|m|={\rm sgn}(m)$. To do the integral set $x= m^2 \sinh^2 t$
$$
I= \frac 1 {|m|} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh^3 t} 2 \sinh t \cosh t dt\\
=\frac 1{|m|} \int_1^\infty  \frac{2}{\cosh^2 t}d \cosh t\\
= \frac 2 {|m|} \int_1^\infty \frac 1{\tau^2}d\tau\\
= \frac{2}{|m|}
$$

There is, of course, an even easier way: set $z= x+m^2$....

Comment: The integral in the figure has a single power of $x$ not $x^2$ (as you have written in your answer) in the denominator. I think in the figure $x=k^2$.

Comment: @hft Ah! that accounts for the factor. I'll chnage my answer

Comment: @mike stone thanks !!